# is Magento2 supports the multiple coupons from same rule?

Tags: magento2, cart, shopping-cart-price-rules, third-party-module, coupon-codes

I'm using the 3rd party extension for multiple coupons extension. it working as differnt rules apply but I need same rule different coupons need to apply in the cart.

this is work in magento2?

my requirement is multiple coupons from the same rule to be applied on the cart
is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a batch of coupons for the same rule with native Magento functionality. Check here: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/marketing/price-rules-cart-coupon.html#method-2-generate-a-batch-of-coupons